# How to put preceding 0 using DataFormatString when exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, gridview

I need to display column Excel exported from gridview in following format,
001, 002, 003, so on.

DataFormatString="{0:000D}" keeps putting "D" at the end of number, 
like 001D, 002D, 003D...

I have tried using {0:D2} and this generates an error.

What would be the proper format string?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the 'D'. `DataFormatString="{0:000}"`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just have realized it appears not working because I'm looking at exported result(to excel).

Comment: I was not clear on the issue on initial post. The problem was specific to exporting to Excel. I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Following DataFormatString fixed issue in exported Excel column.

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sort" DataField="SORT_ORD" DataFormatString='="{0:000}"'/>
```

Comment: Didn't I recommend removing the 'D' as well?